# В чем суть данной реализации сортировки слиянием? (Интересует сама функция merging)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, реализация

Добрый день всем кто читает! Возник вопрос с пониманием самого слияния в сортировке слиянием, каким образом это происходит в данном примере кода, и за что отвечает каждый цикл while и for.

Непонятен этот кусок:

```
void merging(int *firstMas, int *secondMas, int low, int mid, int high) {
int l1, l2, i;

for (l1 = low, l2 = mid + 1, i = low; l1 <= mid && l2 <= high; i++) {
    if (firstMas[l1] <= firstMas[l2])
        secondMas[i] = firstMas[l1++];
    else
        secondMas[i] = firstMas[l2++];
}

while (l1 <= mid)
    secondMas[i++] = firstMas[l1++];

while (l2 <= high)
    secondMas[i++] = firstMas[l2++];

for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
    firstMas[i] = secondMas[i];
}
```

Вызов идет отсюда:

```
void merge_sort(int *firstMas, int *secondMas, int low, int high) {
int mid;

if (low < high) {
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    merge_sort(firstMas, secondMas, low, mid);
    merge_sort(firstMas, secondMas, mid + 1, high);
    merging(firstMas, secondMas, low, mid, high);
}
else {
    return;
}
}
```

Еще раз повторюсь, что хотелось бы пояснение по внутреннему устройству merging, а именно за какие случаи отвечают форы и вайлы.

Благодарю заранее за помощь!!

Comment: а что вам непонятно? Просто возьмите 2 списка (именно списка для простоты) уже отсортированных и напишите код как слить их в 1. Получится что-то похожее.

Comment: @pavel , хорошо, извиняюсь если вопрос до простого глуп, просто пытался в голове провернуть все вместе с рекурсией

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом цикле for

```
for (l1 = low, l2 = mid + 1, i = low; l1 <= mid && l2 <= high; i++) {
    if (firstMas[l1] <= firstMas[l2])
        secondMas[i] = firstMas[l1++];
    else
        secondMas[i] = firstMas[l2++];
}
```

происходит сортировка значений из первого массива с последующей записью их во второй массив. Тобишь, если левое число меньше правого, то переписывается левое, иначе - правое. Следующие за for циклы while необходимы для того, чтобы, если цикл for закончился раньше, чем были переписаны все цифры, все оставшиеся были переписаны во второй массив автоматом, так как в сортировке уже не нуждаются (нет относительно чего сортировать, так как один из отрезков: до середины или после - уже закончился).

Последний же цикл for просто переписывает отсортированные значения из второго в первый массив. Кстати, не совсем понятно зачем изначально передается два массива, т.к. второй массив не несет полезной информации, которая могла бы быть использована за пределами ф-ции сортировки. Это просто буфер. Можно избавится от него в определении ф-ции и просто добавить динамическое выделение необходимой памяти под второй массив прямо в ф-ции.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутое объяснение.

Comment: всегда пожалуйста.